# my server program can be seen as process what is meaning of S in ps output

Tags: c, network-programming, ps

Here is my server program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/un.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main ()
{
int server_sockfd,client_sockfd;
int server_len,client_len;
struct sockaddr_un server_address;
struct sockaddr_un client_address;
unlink("server_socket");
server_sockfd=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);//created socket
server_address.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
strcpy(server_address.sun_path,"server_socket");
server_len=sizeof(server_address);
bind(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,server_len);//binded it
listen(server_sockfd,5);
while (1)
        {
 char ch;
 printf("server waiting\n");
 client_len=sizeof(client_address);
 client_sockfd=accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,&client_len);
 read(client_sockfd,&ch,1);
 ch++;
 write(client_sockfd,&ch,1);
 close(client_sockfd);

}

}
```

I compiled the above program as follows

```
 cc server.c -o server.o
```

when I run a `ps -el | grep server.o` I get following output

```
0 S  1000  4450  2228  0  80   0 -   965 skb_re pts/0    00:00:00 server.o
```

I want to know what is the meaning of `S` in the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "Interruptible sleep". It likely means it is waiting in a blocking system call. In your case that system call is most likely `accept` or `read`.

`ps(1)`

> Here are the different values that the
>   s, stat and state output specifiers
>   (header "STAT" or "S") will display to
>   describe the state of a process.

```
   D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
   R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
   S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
   T    Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
   W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
   X    dead (should never be seen)
   Z    Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
```

Comment: what does interruptible sleep means?

Comment: @Registered User: In an interruptible sleep the process handles signals. If it's in an uninterruptible sleep, signal processing is postponed. [More on the subject](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144)

Answer (score 2):

> - **`S`    Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20
>     seconds.**
> - `D`  Marks a process in disk (or other short term, uninterruptible)
>     wait.
> - `I`  Marks a process that is idle (sleeping for longer than about 20
>     seconds).
> - `L`  Marks a process that is waiting to acquire a lock.
> - `R`  Marks a runnable process.
> - `T`  Marks a stopped process.
> - `W`  Marks an idle interrupt thread.
> - `Z`  Marks a dead process (a "zombie").

[Source](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=ps)